# Importing from subfolder in Python

Tags: python, import

This is the situation. I'm using Python 3.6

I currently have the next folder organization:

```
/MainProject
  __init__.py
    /Folder1
      pyscript1.py
      pyscript2.py
      __init__.py
    /Folder2
      pyscript3.py
      __init__.py
```

So, I'm trying to get a function that exists in pyscript1.py from pyscript3. I've also added a **init**.py at every level. Inside pyscript3.py I tried the following:

```
from . import Folder1
```

Giving the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Folder1'
```

Also I tried:

```
from .Utils import script1
```

Giving the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.Utils'; '__main__' is not a 
package
```

I know that I can solve it using sys and os in the following manner:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('../..'))
```

But I wanted to know if this is possible without using sys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that `Folder1` is a directory, the `.py` scripts are your modules.

In `pyscript3` you should be able to go:

```
from Folder1 import pyscript1
```

Then you can access a method with name `methodname` like:

```
pyscript1.methodname()
```

Otherwise you can import the method directly like:

```
from Folder1.pyscript1 import methodname
```

and use it like:

```
methodname()
```

EDIT:

For your program to see `Folder1` and `Folder2`, you need to run your program from the `MainProject` folder.

Either move `pyscript3` to your `MainFolder` or write another script, let's call it `main.py`, and call the necessary code to instantiate the class/call the function you want in `pyscript3.py`.

To summarize, you always want to run the entry module from the base folder of your project.

Comment: That's the issue I commented, I Get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Folder1'

Comment: You can't import Folder1, but you can import a script from Folder1.  Can you maybe expand on your MainProject folder? Where is the entry-point?

Comment: I'm trying to get from pyscript3 to pyscript1, the entry point would be pyscript3.

Comment: Could you show your main.py or equivalent file?  Presumably it's in the MainProject folder?

Comment: Also, how are you running your program?  Simply `python main.py`?

Comment: python pyscript3.py

Comment: Thanks for the response man. It seems like there is no workaround this, only create a script from the base project

Comment: No problem dude.  Yeah that is the recommended way of structuring your project and executing your program.

Answer (score 0):

If still not working, check the PYTHONPATH Environment Variable you defined for your project. Sometimes one defines a PYTHONPATH just for the root folder of the project but wants to import modules from a folder that is inside the PYTHONPATH that is defined.

Options to solve this:

1. Import the module adding the parent folder name, for example:
   `import MainProject.Folder1.pyscript1` instead of `import Folder1.pyscript1`.
2. Add another PYTHONPATH for the subfolder in which you have the modules to import.

Answer (score -1):

You could use
`from ..Folder1 import pyscript1`
In pyscript3.py
But you would have to load pyscript3 from the parent module or in your case MainProject.

Comment: That is two levels above, and doesn't work, and I can't load pyscript3 from the parent module, also if I use ..Folder1, that gives: ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package