# Import function from script in subfolder

Tags: python, import, spyder, subdirectory

I know similar questions have been asked [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295385/importing-from-subfolder-in-python), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222913/python-imports-from-subfolders), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245508/load-py-file-from-path-folder) times.

I read them thoroughly and tried plenty of solutions but apparently I can't find a way to make it work for me. So I believe this question is not a duplicate.

I have the following structure:

```
+ C:\etc.\etc.\maindir   <---Root Directory
|     mymainfile.py
|     __init__.py        <---this is empty
+     \AuxFun            <--- Subfolder
|         __init__.py    <---this contains: "from . import *"
|         myauxfun1.py
|         myauxfun3.py
```

Now, inside my main (`mymainfile.py`) I have:

```
from AuxFun.myauxfun1 import AuxFun1
import AuxFun.myauxfun3 as AuxFun3
```

each `myauxfun` consists of a single function :

```
def fun()
...
return output
```

**The script works perfectly on jupyter notebook 5.6.0 with Python 3.7 (and IPython 6.5)**

**However it doesn't work on Spyder 3.3.1 with Python 3.7**.

and when trying to import, the console returns:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AuxFun'`

I originally tried without any `__init__.py` file and with a totally empty `__init__.py` in the subfolder.

I also tried the following:

```
from AuxiliaryFunctions import *
from .AuxFun.myauxfun1 import AuxFun1
import KR.AuxFun.myauxfun2 as AuxFun2
```

which return respectively:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AuxiliaryFunctions'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.AuxiliaryFunctions'; '__main__' is not a package
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'KR'
```

Interestingly (for me) the autocompletion recognizes the folder and files.
i.e. if I type: "`.`<kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd>" the `AuxFun` subfolder appears.
Alike, typing "`.AuxFun.`<kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd>" will display all the auxfun scripts within the subfolder.

Comment: Your init files have the wrong name. They need to be named `__init__.py`, not `__init.py__`

Comment: Also, if you want this to work in Spyder, you need to define a project for your work placed in `C:\etc.\etc.\maindir`. You can create a new project by going to the menu `Projects > New project`.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba the `__init__.py` are named correctly, that was a typo. I just fixed it. I'll check if that solves it but I verified that `cd` returns the correct path already (`C:\etc.\etc.\maindir`), so I am not sure this will fix it.